# Logic for username exist in database for grails

Tags: database, grails

I have some troubles thinking for a logic and I don't know how to fix this. Basically what I am trying to do is to unable add an extra user in it with the same username. This is how its done.

```
String select = "select username from user"
def sot = sql.rows(select)

sot.find() {
   def count = it["username"]
   if (params.username != count) {
      String queryname = "insert into user (username, class) values('" + params.username + "','" + params.class1 + "')"
      println(queryname)
      def Query1 = sql.executeInsert(queryname)
      [ Query1: Query1]
      flash.message = "Successfully added user " + params.username
      return true
   }
   else {
      flash.message = "Username exist"
      return true
   }
}
```

So what happens is when the user is added, the loop while stop, same for the check. However if i put return false for the else condition. The user will repeatedly being added for a few times until the loop stops checking. So is there anyone out there can solve this?? Thank you guys so much.

P.S This is just a testing and I will implement SQL injection prevention at a later time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is honestly a textbook case of worst-case database programming. You're going to loop through every username in the database looking for one of them when you could simply use a `where` clause in your SQL. This is fine when there are 10 users, but consider the performance when you have a million.

Try this (and as an added bonus I've fixed your SQL injections):

```
def row = sql.firstRow(
   'select count(*) from user where username=?',
   [params.username])

if (row[0]) {
   flash.message = "Username exist"
   return true
}

sql.executeUpdate(
   'insert into user (username, class) values(?, ?)',
   [params.username, params.class1])

flash.message = "Successfully added user " + params.username
return true
```

Comment: Not to mention since this is a Grails app he isn't using HQL or the objects themselves.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. It works now and I learn quite a lot from this :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a User domain object then you can avoid using SQL all together and use [dynamic finders](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#finders) instead.

```
if(User.findByUsername(params.username)){
    flash.message = "username exist"
}
else{
    new User(username:params.username).save()
}
```